# How can I 'cycle' though similar blocks of HTML using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape info from each of the `"item watching"` in the `"items"` class.  I'm stuck because when I try `find` it only finds the HTML for the first "item watching" but I don't want to use `find_all` because it gives a massive blob that I can't prettify and it would make it more difficult to cycle through the information.

[image: Image for reference]

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser") # SOUP
class_items = soup.find("div", attrs={"data-name":"watching"}).find("div", class_="items") # Narrowed Down

actual_items = class_items.find("div", class_="item watching") # Was thinking [x] so I can cycle?
```

The whole shabang:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
payload = {"username":"?????", "password":"?????"}
url = "https://9anime.to/user/watchlist"
loginurl = "https://9anime.to/user/ajax/login"
with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    res = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    class_items = soup.find("div", attrs={"data-name":"watching"}).find("div", class_="items")
    actual_items = class_items.find_next("div", class_="item watching")
    print(actual_items.prettify())
```

site url: https://9anime.to/
login url: https://9anime.to/user/ajax/login

**Expected output for each "item watching" (Similar format for each):**

```html
<div class="item watching">
 <a class="thumb" href="/watch/kaguya-sama-love-is-war-season-2.omkj?ep=7">
  <img alt="Kaguya-sama: Love is War Season 2" src="https://static.akacdn.ru/files/images/2019/10/f53e6536aa7b3b95e6fe4c6d7b8e1a9b.jpg"/>
 </a>
 <a class="link" data-jtitle="Kaguya-sama wa Kokurasetai?: Tensai-tachi no Renai Zunousen" data-tip="/ajax/film/tooltip/omkj?v=5dab1c5b" href="/watch/kaguya-sama-love-is-war-season-2.omkj?ep=7">
  Kaguya-sama: Love is War Season 2
 </a>
 <span class="current">
  7
 </span>
 <div class="info">
  <span class="state old tip" data-id="omkj" data-unwatched="Unwatched" data-value="0" data-watched="Watched" title="Click to change">
   Watched
  </span>
  <span class="status">
   7/12
  </span>
  <span class="dropdown userbookmark" data-id="omkj">
   <i class="icon icon-pencil-square" data-toggle="dropdown">
   </i>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu bookmark choices pull-right" data-id="omkj">
    <li data-value="watching">
     <a>
      <i class="fa fa-eye">
      </i>
      Watching
     </a>
    </li>
    <li data-value="watched">
     <a>
      <i class="fa fa-check">
      </i>
      Completed
     </a>
    </li>
    <li data-value="onhold">
     <a>
      <i class="fa fa-hand-grab-o">
      </i>
      On-Hold
     </a>
    </li>
    <li data-value="dropped">
     <a>
      <i class="fa fa-eye-slash">
      </i>
      Drop
     </a>
    </li>
    <li data-value="planned">
     <a>
      <i class="fa fa-bookmark">
      </i>
      Plan to watch
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider" role="separator">
    </li>
    <li data-value="remove">
     <a>
      <i class="fa fa-remove">
      </i>
      Remove entry
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the URL and expected output?

Comment: You probably want to use `find_next`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely updated my post for you.

Comment: @EvanSchwartzentruber as I don't have login to that site, I'm just guessing: `actual_items = soup.select('div.item.watching:has(div.info)')` will select all `<div>s` with `class="item watching"` that have `div class="info"` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and the [`select` function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
actual_items = soup.select('div.content > div.items > div.item.watching')
for item in actual_items:
    print(item.prettify())
```

Comment: I've looked into CSS selectors and this looks great but I was wondering if there was any way to store each `item.watching` into a list using this method.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `actual_items` is it. It's a list of `bs4.Element.Tag` objects, each object is one of the `item.watching` divs.

Comment: Ahh yes you're correct!   this is exactly what I wanted thank you!

`actual_items[x].prettify()` to access the other itemsd

Answer (score 1):

I am not a beautiful soup expert, but I had a similar problem where using `find_all` and then creating a smaller variable *did* help me to visualize the information.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()

for i in soup:
    class_items = i.find_all("div", class_="item_watching")
    for x in class_items:
        df = df.append({'Actual Items': x.text.strip()}, ignore_index=True)
```